# Subarray within foreach loop php

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach

I have this code here:

```
<?php foreach($blog_posts['post_category'] as $category) {  ?>
```

How can I get this to work?

Basically I have a database with all my blog posts within them, one of the columns is `post_category` I'm trying to make a list out of all these by a foreach statement that gets the results like so:

```
$data['blog_categories'] = $this->db->query("SELECT `post_category` FROM `blog_posts`");
```

This is codeigniter by the way... Then in my view I have the code:

```
<?php foreach($blog_posts['post_category'] as $category) {  ?>
```

I need to display each category in an li...

Comment: Is that all of the code? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Get this to work doesn't give me any clues on what you want it to do or what's not working.

Comment: You need to do the thing there.

Comment: It just stops any code above or below this working... I need to know if I'm allowed to access an array like that?

Comment: explain bit more about your problem

Comment: @ultranaut - you mean the thing with the stuff? Or the other thing?

Comment: @DavidGrenier - Silly question.. obviously ultranaut meant the other thing with that thing on the top. Makes it much faster together with the other stuff.

Comment: What happens when you do this: `var_dump(is_array($blog_posts['post_category']))` ?

Comment: In all seriousness @swenflea we need to see a bit more to understand what it is you're trying to do and what's not working. What you have looks like how you iterate through an array - but if we saw more and knew what wasn't working we can help diagnose the issue.

Comment: N.B. what you're trying do won't work unless you do the thing before.

Comment: Is my answer what you were after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wanna use implode I think

```
$output = array();
forreach($blog_posts['post_category'] as $item){
    $output[] = "<li>$item</li>";
}
echo "<ul>".implode('',$output)."</ul>";
```

Or if you were just after the list items and not list just replace the last line with

```
echo implode('',$output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure what you're looking for is

```
$data['blog_categories'] = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT `post_category` FROM `blog_posts`");
foreach ($data['blog_categories'] as $category) {
  echo "<li>$category</li>";
}
```

Me, I'd change `$data['blog_categories']` to just `$blog_categories` or something, but I kept it as you had it so as not to confuse the issue.